# Can I put an image in the background of the chart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart.

I want to put an image on the background of the chart, but I only know to change the background color.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I am using a v2.2.4 `jar` file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: XAxis xl = barChart.getXAxis();
xl.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLineText));

YAxis rightAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLineText));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: It's settled immediately.
Thanks :-) !